# How to remove this gray color from topbar/status bar

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app where I have set the top bar / status bar to ascent colors, its working for most screens on lollipop but having an issue on one of the screen its an activity. The code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.realsales.reatsalesapp.activities.EditContactActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarEC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarEC">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarEC">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextTitleEC"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:hint="title"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout18"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_local_hotel_black_48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="bed" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:src="@drawable/shower1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="bath" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:hint="car" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And when I launch it, it looks as follows:

[image: Screen shot of activity on nexus 7]

For most of the other activities it's working fine.
I am not getting what's causing this.

My colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary_500">#FF9800</color>
    <!--Indigo 700-->
    <color name="primary_700">#F57C00</color>

    <!--Pink 500-->
    <color name="accent_500">#2196F3</color>
    <!--Pink 700-->
    <color name="accent_700">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="black_trans80">#33000000</color>

    <color name="tab_scroll_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

And style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_700</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Additional information**

This activity is loaded after another activity which also has same issue I think that might be a cause, basically it has CollapsingToolBar in it. It's code is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutVG"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_group_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_group_imageViewGroupHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/view_group_anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Added manifest as well on request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.realsales.reatsalesapp" >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.AddLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_location" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ViewGroupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_group" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.EditContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_contact" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Sree why would that make a different `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`?

Comment: post your styles.xml and the colors.xml

Comment: @sree kindly explain what do you mean , i am doing this as per material design guidelines and for other activities the top bar is in the ascent color only only this and one other activity is having it like this.

Comment: @Sree But that is for hiding the status bar.

Comment: @sree please check additional info current theme has worked on other activities fine.

Comment: do you test this in any other device ?

Comment: @sree you are overlooking the fact , check my code perfectly has whatever is needed as as explained it has worked for other activities kindly don't overlook fact , i know material design very well

Comment: @sree yes same on nexus 5 , this happens once an activity with collpasibleToolbar is loaded , that activity too has same issue

Comment: any way plz post your manifest too, just that theme part

Comment: @Sree have added manifest as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in Your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`

check `android:statusBarColor` change it to black color(as you want to remove gray color, and have normal look)

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yourColor</item>
```

and remove these below lines of code from `styles.xml`

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> 
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: kindly explain normal look

Comment: statusBarColor if You provide as black than it wont affect your app theme across your app(most apps has black status bar only, so I am talking about that) Thanks

Comment: Also, android:statusBarColor only works for API level 21

Comment: no use then as my app has compatibility from Api level 9 onwards

Comment: I think you should change it in values-21 styles.xml and below 21 API you wont face this issue(status bar color will be black only)

Comment: So you mean if I add status bar color in theme for v21 this gray bar will acquire the ascent color ?

Comment: nope didn't help i think its related to Appbarlayout from android design library in the caller activity as when i start that activity the bar turns grey that layout i have added can you take a look

Comment: @vishal if you will remove these two lines from your code in styles.xml than it should resolve your issue <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

Comment: now this issue should be fixed as i have used and tested your styles its creating same issue just like you so removed <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item> did the trick !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87301/discussion-between-shishram-and-vishal).

Comment: removing `windowTranslucentStatus` worked for me. `fitsSystemWindows` should be set to true on root layout to set correct top padding.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your colors.xml, one of these should have the grey color.

- colorPrimaryDark
- android:statusBarColor

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I want to share this simple solution to this problem.
Just add this line in your `<style></style>` tag in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```